# localStorage salvar alguns campos

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Como eu uso o "localStorage" para salvar alguns campos do meu formulário.

```js
<script>    
    var entrada = document.getElementById('rua');
    var entrada2 = document.getElementById('bairro');

    var paragrafo = document.getElementById('mostrar');

    document.getElementById('salvar').addEventListener('click', function() {

      localStorage.rua = entrada.value;
      localStorage.bairro = entrada2.value;


      mostrar.innerText += localStorage.rua;
      mostrar.innerText += localStorage.bairro;
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' id='rua'>
  <input type='text' id='bairro'>
  <input type='button' id='salvar' value='Salvar'>
</form>

<p id='mostrar'></p>
```

Parecido com isso

Comment: Em menos de 5 minutos no Google você consegue a sua resposta.

Comment: Eu sugeriria que vc revisasse o texto da pergunta. Está confuso de entender. O que seria isso de "Solução:"?

Comment: esse solução seria um campo de como usuario resolveu o problema, não entrei muito no detalhe do campo solução por que o preenchimento desse campo muda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa criar um localStorage para cada campo. Basta criar um array de objetos onde cada objeto da array terá chaves com as informações, algo do tipo:

```
[
   {"rua": "rua 1", "bairro": "bairro A"},
   {"rua": "rua 2", "bairro": "bairro B"}
]
```

Mas como o localStorage só salva informações em forma de string, você terá que usar `JSON.stringify()` para converter a array em string.

Abaixo um exemplo de como você faria isso (comentários explicativos no código):

```
var entrada = document.getElementById('rua');
var entrada2 = document.getElementById('bairro');
var paragrafo = document.getElementById('mostrar');

document.getElementById('salvar').addEventListener('click', function(){
   // cria um objeto com os valores dos campos
   var dados = { "rua": entrada.value, "bairro": entrada2.value };
   // puxa o localStorage para uma variável
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("infos");

   // verifica se o localStorage já existe
   if(ls){
      // converte o localStorage em array
      var json = JSON.parse(ls);
      // adiciona o objeto à array
      json.push(dados);
      // converte a array em string para salvar no localStorage
      json = JSON.stringify(json);
      // sobrescreve o localStorage com novos valores
      localStorage.setItem("infos", json);
   }else{
      // se não existe, cria com uma array convertida em string com os dados
      localStorage.setItem("infos", JSON.stringify([dados]));
   }

   // puxa novamente o localStorage atualizado em forma de array
   var ls_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("infos"));

   // cria uma string vazia
   var texto = '';

   // percorre a array do localStorage e alimenta a string vazia "texto"
   for(var item of ls_array){
      texto += "Rua: "+ item.rua +"<br>Bairro: "+ item.bairro +"<br><br>";
   }

   // insere o HTML em "texto" no <p>
   paragrafo.innerHTML = texto;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
var nome = "João";

// insere o valor da variável "nome" no localStorage
localStorage.setItem("nome", nome);

// printa o valor da varável "nome" direto do localStorage
console.log(localStorage.getItem("nome"));
```