# Como salvar um To-Do-List no localstorage no javascript?

Tags: javascript

É bem simples o que quero fazer: No HTML tem um **input** aonde a pessoa entra com as informações, eu pego ela e salvo no **localstorage**, porem **localstorage.setIten()** ele sobrescreve, então quero salvar as informações em um **array** e exibir no **HTML** dentro de uma **li**.

**Ex**: a pessoa entra no input com as informações = maça, abacaxi, uva

quero salvar ela no **localstorage** assim: **Key seria "frutas"** e **Value seria [maça, abacaxi, uva]**

Estou mandando o código que tentei fazer mas me perdi, alguém poderia me ajudar com o jeito mais fácil de fazer isso ?.

Obrigado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Lista de Compras</h1>

    <input type="text"  id="input">
    <button id="button">Compras</button>

    <button id="delete">Deletar</button>

    <ul id="lista"></ul>

    <script>

        const buttton = document.querySelector('#button')
        const input = document.querySelector('#input')
        const lista = document.querySelector('#lista')
        const deletar = document.querySelector('#delete')

        let array = []
        
        buttton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            array.push(input.value)

            localStorage.setItem('compras', JSON.stringify(array))

            let aa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras'))
            
            aa.map(x => {
                return(
                    lista.innerHTML = `
                        <li>
                            ${x}
                        </li>
                        `
                )
            })

            
            input.value = ''

        })

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
            lista.innerHTML = `
                <li>
                    ${localStorage.getItem('compras')}
                </li>
            `
        })

        deletar.addEventListener('click', () => {
            localStorage.clear()
            lista.remove()

            input.value = ''
        })
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: está correto, só acho que falta um '{elemento}.innerHTML = ' antes do map, e um '.join("")' depois, e que invés da variável local 'aa' seja usado a 'array'.

Comment: eu vi que deram um -1, a pergunta ficou ruim pessoal ?, não conseguiram entender. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Sua pergunta é parecida com esta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399129/localstorage-salvar-alguns-campos?rq=1

Comment: Tudo bem LeAndrade, eu olhei antes de fazer a pergunta e não é o que eu quero fazer, quero adicionar um array no local storage e depois ler ele no html. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu dei uma pesquisada e realizei testes e não é possível armazenar `array` em `localStorage` ele automaticamente converte o `array` em `string`, um `array` que seria exemplo `var arrayFrutas = ['maça', 'abacaxi', 'uva']` ao colocar esse `array` no `localStorage` ele se torna uma `string` `maça, abacaxi, uva`. Não sendo possível buscar elementos por `index` ou por `value`.

Mas existe uma solução, como o `localStorage` armazena os dados permanentemente até que não seja "limpos" com um `clear()`, você pode pegar esta `string` do `localStorage` separados elementos por vírgula e com o método `split()` transformar essa string em um array.

O método `split()` divide uma `String` em uma lista ordenada de `substrings`, coloca essas `substrings` em um `array` e retorna o `array`.

Syntax:

```js
str.split([separator[, limit]])
```

Depois para colocá-los em `array`, é só fazer um `for()` para alocá-los a elementos `<li>`

****PS: É um caminho bem mais fácil e prático do que o que você está fazendo.***

### Teste:

```html



    
    
    Document

```
<h1>Lista de Compras</h1>

<input type="text"  id="input">
<button id="button">Compras</button>

<button id="delete">Deletar</button>

<ul id="lista"></ul>

<script>

    const buttton = document.querySelector('#button')
    const input = document.querySelector('#input')
    const lista = document.querySelector('#lista')
    const deletar = document.querySelector('#delete')

    let array = []

    let storageArray = localStorage.compras? localStorage.compras.split(','):localStorage.setItem('compras', array);
    
    buttton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (input.value.length > 0){
        array.push(input.value)
        localStorage.compras.length > 0? localStorage.compras += ','+array: localStorage.compras = array;
        }
        

    })

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
        for (let i in storageArray){
            lista.innerHTML += `<li>${storageArray[i]}</li>`
        }
        
    })

    deletar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.clear()
        lista.remove()

        input.value = ''
    })
</script>
```

```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, esse código:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
            lista.innerHTML = `
                <li>
                    ${localStorage.getItem('compras')}
                </li>
            `
        })
```

Você deveria iterar sobre os items do `localStorage` para evitar de inserir somente um array(string parecendo array) e aparecer somente o array dentro do `li`.

Reescreva desta forma, iterando sobre os items salvos e adicionando-os a lista:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras')).forEach(el => {
    lista.innerHTML += `
            <li>
                ${el}
            </li>
        `;
  })
});
```

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras'))` para converter em array de fato para podermos iterar sobre ele. Use o `+=` para concatenar os elementos dentro da lista. Usar somente o `=` vai sobreescrever os dados.

Depois, tente usar o valor de `array` para recuperar todos os items salvos, fazer o `push` do novo valor, e entao `array` terá os valores antigos e o novo valor. Para ver que os dados foram persistidos, pegue todos os valores salvos e atribua a `items` e faça um `console.log(items)` para confirmar que foram salvos os valores. Depois, na lista, apenas acrescente o novo valor dentro de uma `li`, somente para mostrar que o valor foi salvo, inserindo:

```
lista.innerHTML += `
                  <li>
                      ${input.value}
                  </li>
                  `;
```

desta forma:

```js
buttton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras')) || [];

  array.push(input.value);

  localStorage.setItem('compras', JSON.stringify(array));

  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras'));

  lista.innerHTML += `
                  <li>
                      ${input.value}
                  </li>
                  `;

  input.value = '';
});
```

Note que novamente usei `+=` pois nçao quero sobreescrever os dados já inseridos na lista. Quando recarregar a página, os dados salvos ainda serão exibidos.

- Dica: Faca uma verificacão para não salvar valores vazios.

Mantenha o restante do seu código como está.

Código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lista de Compras</h1>

    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <button id="button">Compras</button>

    <button id="delete">Deletar</button>

    <ul id="lista"></ul>

    <script>
      const buttton = document.querySelector('#button');
      const input = document.querySelector('#input');
      const lista = document.querySelector('#lista');
      const deletar = document.querySelector('#delete');

      buttton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras')) || [];

        array.push(input.value);

        localStorage.setItem('compras', JSON.stringify(array));

        let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras'));

        lista.innerHTML += `
                  <li>
                      ${input.value}
                  </li>
                  `;

        input.value = '';
      });

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('compras')).forEach((el) => {
          lista.innerHTML += `
            <li>
                ${el}
            </li>
        `;
        });
      });

      deletar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        lista.innerHTML = '';

        input.value = '';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.